# ui-sref in parent div overriding all nested links

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

We have a series of notifications and want to make the overall item clickable to the related item. This has been implemented using `ui-sref` and functions correctly. However, within that, there are to be a series of nested links that go to other relevant information. The problem at the moment is this parent `ui-sref` overrides all of these links. I've tried implementing these nested links as standard anchor and `ui-sref` but it has the same effect. So the hyperlink shows correctly, and when clicking on it, it goes to it for a split second, then reverts back to the `ui-sref` link.

Here is a code example:

```
<div class="NotificationItemBalanced">
    <div class="notificationItem" ui-sref="community.act({slug: slug, id: id})">
        <div class="messageBodyWrapper">
            <span class="messageText"><strong><a ui-sref="user.posts({username: username})"></a></strong> commented on your post</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this related to the `ui-sref` or is there a specific setting in the routes to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: If this is a `ui-sref` problem at all, you could use `ng-click` to intercept the click, verify the source of the click and accordingly redirect to a particular page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a directive like:

```
myApp.directive('preventBubbling', function() {
    return {
        link: function($scope, element) {
             element.on("click", function(e) {
                 e.stopPropagation();
             });
        }
    };
});
```

And add it to your inner links:

```
 <a ui-sref="user.posts({username: username})" prevent-bubbling></a>
```

Basically, when you click on a nested element, the `click` event bubbles up to the DOM tree. So we are simply stopping it to propagate.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

**Update**

Also, if your inner links are inheriting properties from parent `ui-sref` then you should use `ui-sref-opts` as well:

```
<a ui-sref="user.posts({username: username})" ui-sref-opts="{inherit: false}" prevent-bubbling></a>
```